# bootstrap-datepicker don't work

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm beginner in jQuery, but I try my best, I'm probably doing some stupid mistake, but I cannot figure it out.

Problem is simple, `bootstrap-datepicker` don't work.
My code:

```js
$('#sandbox-container .input-group.date').datepicker({
  todayBtn: "linked",
  //language: "pl",
  orientation: "top auto",
  autoclose: true,
  todayHighlight: true
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo BASE_URI;?>/templates/cms/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
<script src="<?php echo BASE_URI;?>/templates/cms/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>  
<link href="<?php echo BASE_URI;?>/templates/cms/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="<?php echo BASE_URI;?>/templates/cms/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.6.1/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
 
<div class="input-group date">
  <input type="text" class="form-control">
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Is `#sandbox-container` missing?

Comment: you are right, good point!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with a solution

```js
$('.input-group.date').datepicker({
  todayBtn: "linked",
  //language: "pl",
  orientation: "auto",
  autoclose: true,
  todayHighlight: true
});
```

```html
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>  
 <script src="http://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.6.1/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>

 <div class="input-group date">
   <input type="text" class="form-control">
   <span class="input-group-addon">
     <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i>
   </span>
</div>
```

You are missing `#sandbox-container` in `HTML`

**Solution With `#sandbox-container`**

```js
$('#sandbox-container .input-group.date').datepicker({
  todayBtn: "linked",
  //language: "pl",
  orientation: "auto",
  autoclose: true,
  todayHighlight: true
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>  
<script src="http://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.6.1/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>

<div id="sandbox-container">
  <div class="input-group date">
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: this works, thank you. I'm missing jQuery's fundamentals. May I ask also how to configure/link css for this?

Comment: @gileneusz Welcome buddy :)  I didn't get the configure of `CSS`, please elaborate on that?

Comment: great! and how to add polish language? ;)

Comment: @gileneusz Use `jquery i18n` to add different language

Answer (score 1):

What r u trying to reach ? ur **#sandbox-container** is not contained in ur code and if u trying to put multiple classes/Ids Selector u should separate them with
**,**  like that :

```
$('#sandbox-container, .input-group, .date') .........
```

Comment: you are right, i tried to reach <div class="input-group date">

Comment: @gileneusz np u can vote me up xD , to use css commend in ur Jquery u can do this : $('.Class').css(" here just write ur css code u want");

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your javascript in a `$(document).ready()`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.input-group.date').datepicker({
    todayBtn: "linked",
    //language: "pl",
    orientation: "top auto",
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true
    });
} );
```

Comment: I put my script in the bottom of the page, but it is a good recomendation to add $(document).ready():